# Backup of GRUB2 on both UEFI and BIOS systems

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10, bios

Currently I have two laptops dual booting Ubuntu 19.04 and Windows 10:

1. Asus G74SX - dual boot on the same SSD (BIOS)
2. Dell XPS 13 9350 - dual boot on the same NVMe SSD (UEFI)

I have both laptops backed up with Macrium Reflect but I always have this fear that the image backups do not restore the GRUB2 somehow.

Comment: Just have a bootable live installer of Ubuntu and know how to add Boot-Repair. Then you can always restore grub boot loader to MBR for BIOS and to ESP for UEFI boot. On UEFI system just be sure to boot in UEFI boot mode to restore UEFI version of grub. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair  If you know the commands to mount required partitions, you can just restore grub using live installer without Boot-Repair. If grub is damaged, you may need Internet to do a full reinstall of grub which then includes all the configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

read: https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/grub-2.html
Download and burn DVD:   https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/grub-2.html

These can help reset GRUB2 or solve GRUB2 problems.

If you need 'bit by bit' replacement on to a hard rive (old type, SSD or NVMe) you may need similar to Macrium reflect program. I use software from Paragon-software GmbH , Germany "Hard Disk Manager" paid edition but they have free editions available for download. I know it can write completely to a new hard drive exactly what was on old hard drive including GRUB2.

Comment: I only use USB pendrives nowadays. No CDs. Anyways, has anyone have experience restoring from a Macrium image and has no problem on their dual boot configurations?

Comment: Used Macrium ONLY to restore a Windows set up. Never used with a dual boot set up.  I tend to use Paragon Software GmbH Hard Disk Manager for all Windows set ups and as my Linux is usually on an external drive (USB connection) the Linux side is easily restored by a re-instal,